# How do you get one list from a loop that produces multiple lists in Python?

Tags: python, list

Here is my code from Python, I want `occurence` to be one big list. When I run it I just get back many one digit lists, I tried moving the print statement out of the loop, but I only get one answer. Any ideas?

```
import random

rolls = 0
occurrence = []

for i in range(0, 1000):
    dice1 = random.randrange(1, 7)
    dice2 = random.randrange(1, 7)
    rolls = rolls + 1
    occurrence = [dice1 + dice2]
    print(occurrence)
```

Comment: O Okay, that works! Thanks everyone for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `append()`:

```
import random

rolls = 0
occurrence = []

for i in range(0, 1000):
    dice1 = random.randrange(1, 7)
    dice2 = random.randrange(1, 7)
    rolls = rolls + 1
    occurrence.append(dice1 + dice2)

print(occurrence)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of length 2 tuples with random numbers between 1, and 7.

```
occurences = [(random.randrange(1, 7) , random.randrange(1, 7)) for i in range(1000)]
```

Comment: It is unclear whether OP wants tuples or sums of two dice.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from your question this should work:

```
import random

rolls = 0
occurence = []

for i in range(0,1000):
    dice1 = random.randrange(1,7)
    dice2 = random.randrange(1,7)
    rolls = rolls + 1
    occurence.append(dice1 + dice2)  #you need to add each value to the list with append
print (occurence)
```

When you use this:

```
occurence = [dice1 + dice2]
```

That creates a new list each time the `for` loop runs so the result at the end of the `for` loop is a list with a single number.

Comment: This will print the whole list in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

A rather pythonic way would be to use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
occurence = [ (random.randrange(1,7)+random.randrange(1,7)) for _ in range(1000)]
```